# How do I PUT data using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, http, request, httpurlconnection

I want to send an HTTP request using Java to the parse server, here is the request

```
curl -X PUT \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: value" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: value" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
"channels": [
"Giants"
]
}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/installations/mrmBZvsErB
```

To send it I have created a request using HttpURLConnection, I have set the three first params like this

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

But for the last param, I am not sure how to set it to the request?

Answer (score 2):

[On this page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) you can read about `-d` param: `"(HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. [...]`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4206094/2069368) should help you.

Answer (score 2):

That's the data for the request. Using HttpURLConnection you will simply need to write that data to the output stream. Here's an example:

```
//Need to set this first
connection.doOutput(true);
String data = "{ \"channels\": [\"Giants\"]}";
connection.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes(CharSet.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Where connection is your HttpURLConnection.